# How do I know when to use the perfect infinitive and simple infinitive?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference, infinitives, semantics

Most of the time they have the same meaning as in:

> It was stupid of me to say anything on Twitter
>
> It was stupid of me to have said anything on Twitter
>
> Luis deserved to earn that promotion
>
> Luis deserved to have earned that promotion

My question is why there is a perfect infitive? if it can easily be replaced by an infinitive(simple).

Comment: Note that "deserve to earn" is tautological. If you earn something this implies that you deserve it.  In English we would say, "Luis deserved  that promotion" or "Luis earned that promotion" or possibly "Luis deserved to receive that promotion"

Answer (score 1):

Like the past perfect, this form is used to convey looking back from a particular time to an earlier time. Like the past perfect, it is usually optional if the temporal relationships are clear anyway.

There are cases where it is clearly significant eg

> I don't want to tidy the garage, but I want to have tidied the garage.

In your examples, using it says that the speaker is choosing to locate themselves temporally at a later time (possibly the present) and ''look back'' at the event they are describing. The forms without *have* do not make that choice, and don't imply any particular viewpoint.

Idiomatically, I find the past infinitive reasonably likely in the first case - it suggests that the speaker is putting the whole thing behind them, and they have learnt better since. But the simpler form is fine.

In the second case, I can't think of a context in which the past infinitive is likely; but there may be such a context.